# How to control threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I have quite a problem with my program in C. I use 5 threads but 3 threads must work one after another in loop and here comes problem. When i use my program in loop without threads everything works just fine, when i add threads with mutex and cond_signal program looks like don't want to make its work, its working but not changing global  variables. How can i run threads in infinite loop (SIGTERM have to turn off them and free memory) and 3 run one after another. My current idea looks like that:

```
 void thr_func1()
{
  while(1)
  {
    mutex on;
    wait_for_cond();
    /* Some work on global variables */
    mutex off;
    send signal to another thread
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you need something like this in the threads:

```c
int step = ...;    // 0, 1 or 2 depending on the thread.

while (1) {
   wait_for_step( step );

   // Do work here.

   goto_step( ( step + 1 ) % 3 );
}
```

This can be achieved using

```c
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int step = 0;

static void wait_for_step( int a_step ) {
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

   while ( step != a_step )
      pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}

static void next_step( int a_step ) {
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

   step = a_step;
   pthread_cond_broadcast( &cond );

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}
```

But there's no reason to do this! It adds computation and development overhead for nothing. Just use one thread.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I'll check it definitely! I know it add computation for nothing but it's not my idea, I have same feelings about this.